# Conditions to Make $\text{Hom}(M, N) \cong M^* \otimes N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$, $N$, and $L$ be $R$-modules.

When do we have $\text{Hom}(M, N) \cong \text{Hom}(M, R) \otimes N$? I am looking for the most general condition you can think of.

For instance, does this hold when $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated and projective? Is flatness relevant? It definitely holds when $R$ is a field and $M$ and $N$ are finite dimensional.

More generally, when do we have $\text{Hom}(M , N \otimes L) \cong \text{Hom}(M, N) \otimes L$?

Comment: I don't know about the most general condition, but regardless of $M$, "$N$ finitely generated projective" is certainly enough.

Comment: It also works regardless of $N$ if $M$ is finitely generated projective. Now by taking a (f.g.-)projective resolution of a finitely generated $M$, we see that it has to do with the flatness of $N$ indeed: if $M$ is f.g. and $N$ is flat, then it works for those (use the $5$-lemma); so it has something to do with flatness

Comment: (I meant finitely presented, we need two stages in the projective resolution to be finitely generated)